# Why R code autocompletion doesn't work in VSCode even though Intellisense is there

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-r

I'm using [VS code for Mac](https://code.visualstudio.com) `Version: 1.69.2 (Universal)`.
And following the instruction [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/r), I have installed [R Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=REditorSupport.r) (Intellisense included?).

However the autocompletion doesn't work. For example when I type `rno` I expect it to show `rnorm(...)`.

How can I fix this problem?

[image]